# Progress-4GL: How to dynamically add a fill-in in a form and take user input in it?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I've a form in a base QAD mfg/pro (ver 10.2) program. I know the names of form, frame and fields. I'dont have access to base program's code modification. I've a wrapper program that access various fields from the existing form using handles, first-child, next-sibling etc.

What I want to do is to add a fill-in into this form/frame from the wrapper program and during runtime, take user input into that field.

I've been able to create text (for label) and fill-in field (called user) in the frame, however, the field is in't enabled.

```
create fill-in txt_user 
assign
    name = "txt_user"
    row = 7
    column = 19             
    frame = hWidget         
    visible = true           
    side-label-handle = lbl_user.
```

How can I enable the fill-in field `txt_user` and take input in it?

Comment: In your code snipped above you are using "user" as the variable name to hold the reference to the FILL-IN widget. User is a keyword that cannot be used as the name of an identifier (│** The keyword user may not be used as a name. (329) ).

Comment: @MikeFechner Great catch. It was a typo, I've both the variable name and name set to txt_user. I've corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Enable the field set the SENSITIVE property to TRUE. To query the current value, read the INPUT-VALUE property.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, we are using QAD mfg/pro version 10.2, which is a character base version. Are these properties available in character based environments? Can you please put a simple example using sensitive and input-value properties?

Comment: You are already setting a bunch of properties / attributes in your code. Just add SENSITIVE = TRUE to the assign section of the CREATE FILL-IN statement. And it certainly works as expected in character user interface as well.

Comment: Also, is there a way to clear the contents of the fill-in? I've set ````self:screen-value = "".````, which clears the contents of the fill-in, however, cursor remains at the end position of the previously typed text. I've also tried self:clear() but it gives error saying `CLEAR is not a queryable attribute for FILL-IN txt_user. (4052)'

Comment: setting the CURSOR-OFFSET attribute of the FILL-IN to 1 seems to help. In GUI that's not required. Seems to be specific to Character.